# How to search for Docker plugins

Tags: docker, plugins, dockerhub

On the Docker website they show how they install the plugin `vieux/sshfs`:

```
$ docker plugin install vieux/sshfs

Plugin "vieux/sshfs" is requesting the following privileges:
- network: [host]
- capabilities: [CAP_SYS_ADMIN]
Do you grant the above permissions? [y/N] y

vieux/sshfs
```

They also have a section called ***Finding a plugin*** and they show there a [list](https://docs.docker.com/engine/extend/legacy_plugins/#finding-a-plugin) of available plugins.

But they don't show the full list.  For example, the plugin `vieux/sshfs` doesn't appear on their lists.

I found it on the Docker Hub:

[image]

So I understand that the plugins are stored together with the images in the Docker Hub.

How can I search **only** for plugins ?  I don't see any option to mark that I want to see all the exist plugins (not images).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So I understand that the plugins are stored together with the images in the Docker Hub.

You are wrong. Plugins are not **stored** together with the images. Plugins are **distributed** as Docker images. The docs specifically note that [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/extend/#installing-and-using-a-plugin):

> Plugins are distributed as Docker images and can be hosted on Docker Hub or on a private registry.

So on Docker Hub you will not be able to tell if it's a plugin or not, it's an image and is distributed as one. The only way to tell is to know beforehand.

P.S. If you want Docker plugins, check out [Docker store](https://store.docker.com/search?q=&type=plugin) ;)

Comment: I will build something that finds all the plugins, I just need to understand how to identify them as a plugin and not as an image.

Comment: By "The only way to tell is to know beforehand" in my answer I wanted to say that from docker hub you can't say. You will have to take a look at each image.

Comment: I checked Docker store, it looks like you can filter by plugins there. I updated my answer. But on Docker Hub - no luck.